# How to progressively build a group by Linq query?

Tags: c#, linq

Suppose I have the items

```
{ // item 0
    Color = yellow,
    Priority = high,
},
{ // item 1
    Color = yellow,
    Priority = medium,
},
{ // item 2
    Color = green,
    Priority = high,
},
```

I want to be able to progressively build a `GroupBy` query as using `var grouped = items.GroupBy(item => item.Color)`, what in this case I would have 2 groups and then group again using by the key `item.Priority` to have 3 groups.

Unfortunately using `var regrouped = grouped.GroupBy(item => item.Priority)` is not a valid solution.

The final result must be equivalent as doing

```
items.GroupBy(item => new {item.Color, item.Priority});
```

Comment: What type is `grouped`? So in the second expression, what type is `item`? How do you expect the two groups in `grouped` to be split up into three groups? What is wrong with `var groupPri = items.GroupBy(item => item.Priority);`?

Comment: So you want to have two levels of groups? Group first by color and then inside each group group again by priority?

Comment: Did I understand that you want to unwrap grouped to the original collection and group it by another key?!

Comment: The final result would be as querying the original collection by both of keys at the same time.

Comment: Wait, if the final result is equivalent to doing `items.GroupBy(item => new {item.Color, item.Priority});`...why not just do that?

Comment: My current problem is that the second grouping should be conditional, so depending on a previous condition I am going to group by priority or not, but I imagine that it could have other benefits as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to regroup on a subkey as a new object, you can use `ToLookup` to create the `IGrouping`s you need, and `SelectMany` to flatten them into the new `IEnumerable`:

```
var regrouped = grouped.SelectMany(cg => cg.GroupBy(i => i.Priority)
                                           .ToLookup(pg => new { Color = cg.Key, Priority = pg.Key },
                                                     pg => pg.Select(i => i)
                                                    )
                                  );
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you want to group each group of `Color` into `Priority`. If that's the case, this should work:

```
var items = new List<Item>
{
    new Item { Color = "yellow", Priority = "high" },
    new Item { Color = "red", Priority = "high" },
    new Item { Color = "yellow", Priority = "medium" },
    new Item { Color = "red", Priority = "medium" },
    new Item { Color = "green", Priority = "high" },
    new Item { Color = "green", Priority = "high" },
    new Item { Color = "red", Priority = "high" },
};

var groupped = items.GroupBy(x => x.Color);
var regroupped = groupped.Select(x => new
{
    Color = x.Key,
    Priorities = x.GroupBy(y => y.Priority)
});
```

Notice that this returns the same result set than your query

```
var regroupped = items.GroupBy(item => new {item.Color, item.Priority});
```

Comment: It doesn't quite return the same result set. They are (mostly) equivalent, but they are definitely not the same.

Comment: @MattBurland That's weird, a console app with a simple foreach tells me they are the same. Of course, the types are completely different

Comment: You can iterate and get the same objects out, but you do lose, for example, the `Key` property. Which may or may not matter.

Comment: @MattBurland Ah, I see what you mean. The OP didn't post specific requirements so we'll see whether it helps

Comment: And also with this you have 2 groups in the end and one of the groups have 2 groups with 1 item each. What's not the same as having querying with both properties at the same time. You might have a similar behavior with SelectMany though.